# Find the String Starts with $ symbol using Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

```
String str = "hai ${name} .... Welcome to ${sitename}....";
```

from this str i need to replace ${name} by "jack" and ${sitename} by "google"

is it possible to do with regular Expression  ?

or

is there any other fastest way to replace the string .

EDITED :

name and sitename is the str variable is dynamic .

1.So first i have to find the key .
  **Eg : here `name , sitename` is the key**
2.Then i have an Hashmap which has key value pairs .
   based on the key value i have to replace the string in `str` variable.

Comment: This can be done with a regular expression, yes.

Comment: Use regex group to retrieve the name inside the `${}`.

Comment: name and sitename is the str variable is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Replacer
{
    public static String replacePlaceHolders(String text)
    {
        Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<>();

        fields.put("name", "jack");
        fields.put("sitename", "google");

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(.*?)\\}");
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(text);

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String key = matcher.group(1);

            if (!fields.containsKey(key)) {
                continue;
            }

            matcher.appendReplacement(result, fields.get(key));
        }

        matcher.appendTail(result);

        return result.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(
                replacePlaceHolders("hai ${name} .... Welcome to ${sitename}...."));
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what exactly i need. but , there is one problem in this code. after replacing sitename the dots(....) are not appended . can you please update the code. I'm new to regular expression.

Comment: I already edited.  The call to `matcher.appendTail(result)` needs to be added.

Answer (score 1):

NO Regex is needed!

You could iterate the keySet of your map, and do:

```
str=str.replace("${"+key+"}", map.get(key));
```

about the method:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off using [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
String str = String.format("hai %s .... Welcome to %s....", name, site);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
\$\{name+\}
```

change ${name} to test

-> ${name} trete ${sitename}  -> test trete ${sitename}

You have to escape this expression for usage in Java:

```
\\$\\{name+\\}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can replace `${name}` and `${sitename}` with `{0}` and `{1}` you could use [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html).

```
String str = "hai {0} .... Welcome to {1}....";
String output = MessageFormat.format(str, new String[]{"jack","google"});
```